# Extract information from user input using Regex in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to access this only parts of user input. Eg. if user inputs a file name like /file/path/test_324_3422.jpg

I want to get only test, 324 and 3422

I have been attempting this, but it does not work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

if(@ARGV != 1){
    print "Error\n";
}
else{
    my $input = $ARGV[0];
    $input =~ /(.)_([\d]+)_([\d]+)/
    print $1, "\n";


}
```

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/sA4fK9

Comment: `$1` refers to your first capturing group, if you want to display the content of group 2  and 3, use `$2` and `$3`. Change your first group description to `([^\/_]+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot `.` inside your capture group is only matching a single character.

And you are only printing `$1` which is the match of the first capturing group. You need `$2` and `$3` also if you want to display the matches of those capturing groups as well.

```
my $input =~ /([a-zA-Z]+)_(\d+)_(\d+)/;
print join(', ', $1, $2, $3), "\n";
```

If that does not suit your needs, use a negated match for your first capturing group.

```
my $input =~ /([^\/_]+)_(\d+)_(\d+)/;
```